How to impute OPEN_CLS_STS based on values in DT_CLS in Python
I'm trying to impute the OPEN_CLS_STS based on the values in DT_CLS.
IF DT_CLS has a date populated then OPEN_CLS_STS should have a value 'C'. Otherwise OPEN_CLS_STS should have a value 'O'.
I tried using the function below but it doesn't seem to work:
enter image description here
Any suggestions?

Don't post duplicate questions. Instead, you might want to edit the previous question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want tips.
